# I am trying to filter a visual based on the previous workday and we work some Saturdays

Tags: powerbi, formatting

I am trying to filter a visual to just show the previous 10 workdays instead of 10 relative days. In a sense I want to show the previous 10 data points.

I have seen the answers that show to make a new column based on if it is the weekend or not but that doesn't seem to work in my case considering we work some Saturdays. I have already edited my date column to exclude the Saturdays and Sundays that we are not planning to work. For example, on 7/6, if I select relative date by the previous 10 days and ot not include today, it only shows 6 data points which are June 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, July 5. I would like for it to show the previous 6 days as well as the 25th, 24th, 21st and 20th of June.